# why won't my python desktop pet program do anything when i try to run it when it has no errors detected?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, pyautogui, python-3.10

[Here's the link to the tutorial I followed](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/create-your-own-desktop-pet-with-python-5b369be18868).

When I try to run it from IDLE, it only says RESTART:

`C:\Users\USER\Downloads\pythonpetashy.py` and doesn't do anything

I'm using `Python 3.10.4` on Windows.

And here is the code:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui
x = 1400
cycle = 0
check = 1
idle_num = [1,2,3,4]
popo_num = [13,15]
angy_num = [10,11,12]
walk_left = [5,6,7]
walk_right = [8,9,14]
event_number = random.randrange(1,3,1)
impath = r"C:\Users\USER\Downloads\desktop project"

#transfer random no. to event
def event(cycle,check,event_number,x):
    if event_number in idle_num:
        check = 0
        print('idle')
        window.after(400,update,cycle,check,event_number,x) #no. 1,2,3,4 = idle
    elif event_number in popo_num:
        check = 1
        print('idle to popo')
        window.after(100,update,cycle,check,event_number,x) #no. 13,15 = idle to popo
        
    elif event_number in walk_left:
        check = 3
        print('walking towards left')
        window.after(100,update,cycle,check,event_number,x)#no. 5,6,7 = walk towards left
    
    elif event_number in walk_right:
        check = 4
        print('walking towards right')
        window.after(100,update,cycle,check,event_number,x)#no. 8,9,14 = walk towards right
    
    elif event_number in angy_num:
        check = 2
        print('angy')
        window.after(100,update,cycle,check,event_number,x)#no. 10,11,12 = angy

#make the gif work
def gif_work(cycle,frames,event_number,first_num,last_num) :
    if cycle < len(frames) -1:
        cycle+=1
    else:
        cycle = 0
        event_number = random.randrange(first_num,last_num+1,1)
    return cycle, event_number
def update(cycle,check,event_number,x):
    #idle
    if check ==0:
        frame = idle[cycle]
        cycle ,event_number = gif_work(cycle,idle,event_number,1,9)

    #idle to popo
    elif check ==1:
        frame = idle_to_popo[cycle]
        cycle ,event_number = gif_work(cycle,idle_to_popo,event_number,1,9)

    #angy
    elif check == 2:
        frame = angy[cycle]
        cycle ,event_number = gif_work(cycle,angy,event_number,1,9)

    #walk toward left
    elif check == 3:
        frame = walk_positive[cycle]
        cycle, event_number = gif_work(cycle,walk_positive,event_number,1,9)
        x -= 3

    #walk towards right
    elif check == 4:
        frame = walk_negative[cycle]
        cycle, event_number = gif_work(cycle,walk_positive,event_number,1,9)
        x -= -3
        window.geometry('100x100+'+str(x)+'1050')
        label.configure(image=frame)
        window.after(1,event,cycle,check,event_number,x)

window = tk.Tk()

#call ashy's action .gif to an array
idle = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath+'\idleme.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(8)]#idle gif, 8 frames
idle_to_popo = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath+'\idletopopo.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(13)] #idle to popo gif, 13 frames
angy = [tk.PhotoImage(file= r"C:\Users\USER\Downloads\desktop project\angyme.gif",format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(15)]#angy me gif, 15 frames
walk_positive = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath+'\walkingleft.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(13)]#walking left gif, 13 frames
walk_negative = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath+'\walkingright.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(13)]#walking right gif, 13 frames

#window configuration
window.config(highlightbackground='black')
window.overrideredirect(True)
window.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor','black')
label = tk.Label(window,bd=0,bg='black')
label.pack()

#loop the program
window.after(1,update,cycle,check,event_number,x)
window.mainloop()
```

I'm completely new to the world of Python programming, so I guess it was kind of ambitious for me to attempt to make a more complicated program. I followed everything the tutorial said, but I have no idea why it won't do anything since there aren't any errors detected. Admittedly, I did underestimate the complications of making such a program, but it's supposed to be a gift so I really want this to work.

a bit of explanation on what it's supposed to do, basically it should open a transparent window where the GIFs i've made would show up and move around randomly like a normal desktop pet would.

Comment: I think it would be helpful for you to start cutting bits of this out until you get to a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @theherk tbh i have no clue how to cut bits of the code out without changing the overall function, but ill try to do so! thank youu for the suggestion<3

Comment: What I mean, is that changing the overall function is a critical part of isolating your issue. You are doing a few things here: trying to run a program at all, generating a tk gui, loading an image, doing some animation, etc. Try to write a program to do each one of those things alone. You might start with a simple [hello world](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Hello%2C_World%21), then a plain tk window that lets you click to close. Then, maybe a program to load an image. Once you can do all the pieces alone, you put them together. Along the way, you'll discover what isn't working here, maybe.

Comment: @theherk ohh okaay ive tried doing each of the pieces alone and everything works fine, but for some reason the GIFs that are supposed to show up when i run the original program still wont show up, is there a mistake in the code?

Comment: Is the last three lines inside `update()` in wrong indentation?

Comment: @acw1668 are these lines what you're referring to?         `#loop the program
window.after(1,update,cycle,check,event_number,x)
window.mainloop()`

Comment: No . The last three lines _**inside update() function**_.

Comment: @acw1668 ohh, no, i tried changing those lines' indentation and nothing really happenedd

Comment: just a little update on this in case people used the same tutorial and faced the same problems, i suggest that you give up on following this tutorial and use [this one](https://github.com/ALearningCurve/desktop-pet/blob/main/README.md) instead. especially if you're totally new to this like me, it's way simpler to do :) have a great day and thank you to everyone who tried to help!!

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to name the gifs the same name as they are or you have to allow it to find it in your pc/laptop